# Null values coerced to zero (0) when exporting to csv or txt

Tags: arcmap, r, arcgis-10.2, csv

I extracted values from several rasters, and in some cases, the value is null. However, when I export the attribute table to a csv or a txt file (from ArcMap), the null values are converted to 0. Is there any way to prevent this from happening?
These zeros are a real downer, as throw off my analysis,  which is done in R.

Comment: I used the Extract Multi value to Point in batch mode with .tiff files. The NULL values are really NULL, but when exporting the attribute table (as csv or txt), they become zeros.

Comment: In the feature class attribute table, make sure the field properties allow null values.  By default, this should be "Yes", however, it is worth a check.

Answer (score 3):

So far, the best workaround I've found is to  convert null values to to values, such as -999.99 using the field calculator. Then when I export export the attribute table I can identify these values (-999.99) as being "NULL" in my analysis.